# How to echo the source code of multiple files using file_get_contents PHP?

Tags: php, html, directory, echo, file-get-contents

```
<textarea placeholder="Source code of file" class="source">
<?php echo ($thesource) ?>
</textarea>

    <?php 
       $blacklist = array("one.jps", "two.txt", "four.html");

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) { 
$thesource = file_get_contents($entry);
            echo "<div class='post'
<p>$entry</p>
</div>
";
        }

    }

    closedir($handle);
}
    ?>
```

Output:

```
<textarea placeholder="Source code of file" class="source">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
etc
etc
</body>
</html>
</textarea>

<p>ok.html</p> 
<p>source.php</p>
<p>sub.html</p>
<p>stylesheet.css</p>
```

As confusing this may look, let me try to explain what I want to achieve.

Lets say that there are some files in a directory (4 in this case). The PHP code I am using will echo out all those 4 files onto the page that the PHP code is on - it excludes everything in the blacklist. So it will look a little something like this:

```
<p>ok.html</p> 
<p>source.php</p>
<p>sub.html</p>
<p>stylesheet.css</p>
```

There is also a textarea:

```
<textarea placeholder="Source code of file" class="source">
<?php echo ($thesource) ?>
</textarea>
```

This textarea will have a value of $thesource. Whatever is in the $thesource variable will appear in the textarea.

To define the $thesource variable, this is the PHP code I am using:

```
$thesource = file_get_contents($entry);
```

Note that $entry is all the files that are echoed out onto the page (as explained above - 4 files in this case)

I am trying to make it so that, whenever a user clicks on one of the files:

```
<p>ok.html</p> 
<p>source.php</p>
<p>sub.html</p>
<p>stylesheet.css</p>
```

When the user clicks on those listed above, it will display the source code of the clicked file in the textarea.

The current source code I am using, only echo's out the source code of the current file containing the PHP code.

How would I achieve this? Thanks - and if you are still unsure of what I am trying to achieve, then please ask!

Comment: So you want to execute the php script and just echo the generated html code?

Comment: So you want a list of all files in a specific directory which aren't on the blacklist and if you click on one the file should get displayed in the text area?

Comment: The source code being the PHP? Or the HTML?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do, clicking on one of the files would display the source code of that file in the textarea

Comment: @Osman Also do you want the source code or the parsed php?

Comment: @Rizier123 Just the source code, basically **everything** that is contained in that file, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

First i get all files in a directory with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) which aren't in the blacklist. After that i print a list which you can click on it.

If you click on it the file get's included and displayed in the textarea.

```
<?php

    $blacklist = array("one.jps", "two.txt", "four.html");
    $files = array_diff(glob("*.*"), $blacklist);

    foreach($files as $file)
        echo "<div class='post'><a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "'><p>" . $file . "</p></a></div>";


    if(!empty($_GET["file"]) && !in_array($_GET["file"], $blacklist) && file_exists($_GET["file"])) 
        $thesource = htmlentities(file_get_contents($_GET["file"]));

?>

<textarea rows="40" cols="100" placeholder="Source code of file" class="source"><?php if(!empty($thesource))echo $thesource; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is there anyway to do this without having to visit a new page? Once the user clicks on the file, the script works but however he gets sent to a new URL. Is there anyway to do this all from one page?

Comment: Thanks for your help but as a follow up, is there anyway to do this without having the URL changed to http://example.com/test?file=one.html as this is a major security flaw since users can directly change 'one.html' to whichever file they desire (i,e a PHP file and get access to the PHP code), thanks again

Comment: @Osman You could use the session variable to save the file name in it

Comment: @Osman I'm not too good with AJAX, so i can't help you there very well